# Split, group and count string

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq, regex-group

I would like to split, group and count the occurrences of specific phrases in a large string in C#.

The following pseudo code should give some indication of what I am trying to achieve.

```
var my_string = "In the end this is not the end";
my_string.groupCount(2);

==>
    [0] : {Key: "In the", Count:1}
    [1] : {Key: "the end", Count:2}
    [2] : {Key: "end this", Count: 1}
    [3] : {Key: "this is", Count: 1}
    [4] : {Key: "is not", Count: 1}
    [5] : {Key: "not the", Count: 1}
```

As you will notice, this is not as simple as just splitting the string and counting each sub-string. The example groups every 2 words, but ideally it should be able to handle any number.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, I missed that.

Comment: @GrantWinney - no, the two questions are similar but not the same.

Comment: How do you want to split `input`?

Comment: Assuming you need to deal with LARGE string, I would't recomend you to spliting whole string. You need to go through it, remember last groupCount words and count combinations in dictinary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of how you can approach this:

- Use the regular `Split` method of the `string` to obtain the individual words
- Make a dictionary for the counts
- Go through all pairs of consecutive words, building the composite keys and incrementing counts

Here is how you can implement this:

```
var counts = new Dictionary<string,int>();
var tokens = str.Split(' ');
for (var i = 0 ; i < tokens.Length-1 ; i++) {
    var key = tokens[i]+" "+tokens[i+1];
    int c;
    if (!counts.TryGetValue(key, out c)) {
        c = 0;
    }
    counts[key] = c + 1;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RiiaEB)

Comment: what happens in case of really large strings?

Comment: @gabba The same thing that happens in case of not so large strings :-) The task is linear in the amount of time and memory it requires.

Comment: when you split 2gb string to a tousands of small strings you get more then double memory consumption. We don`t need to do it. All we need to do one scan, and little dictionary.

Comment: @gabba If you do this on a 2gb strings, I bet you have bigger problems than that :-) Optimizing this for memory is kind of useless, because one ends up taking `N-1` substrings in the end anyway, simply to use them as keys.

Comment: I just want to say the question is about large strings, we need to take it in to account. I bet in the books we don't meet such a variety of words. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using an `ILookup<string, string[]>` to count the occurence of each array:

```
var my_string = "In the end this is not the end";
int step = 2;
string[] words = my_string.Split();
var groupWords = new List<string[]>();
for (int i = 0; i + step <= words.Length; i++)
{
    string[] group = new string[step];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < step; ii++)
        group[ii] = words[i + ii];
    groupWords.Add(group);
}
var lookup = groupWords.ToLookup(w => string.Join(" ", w));

foreach(var kv in lookup)
    Console.WriteLine("Key: \"{0}\", Count: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Count());
```

Output:

```
Key: "In the", Count: 1
Key: "the end", Count: 2
Key: "end this", Count: 1
Key: "this is", Count: 1
Key: "is not", Count: 1
Key: "not the", Count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation. I've updated it to move the work into a function, and to allow you to specify an arbitrary group size.

```
public static Dictionary<string,int> groupCount(string str, int groupSize) 
{
    string[] tokens = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

    var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < tokens.Length - (groupSize-1); i++ ) 
    {
        string key = "";
        for ( int j = 0; j < groupSize; j++ ) 
        {
            key += tokens[i+j] + " ";
        }
        key = key.Substring(0, key.Length-1);

        if ( dict.ContainsKey(key) ) {
            dict[key]++;
        } else {
            dict[key] = 1;
        }
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
string str = "In the end this is not the end";
int groupSize = 2;
var dict = groupCount(str, groupSize);

Console.WriteLine("Group Of {0}:", groupSize);
foreach ( string k in dict.Keys ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: \"{0}\", Count: {1}", k, dict2[k]);
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8KZ0MV)

Comment: I'll note it is very similar to dasblinkenlight's take. It uses Split to obtain the individual words, uses a for loop to obtain tokens, and a dictionary to maintain the counts of tokens to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

You can create method which builds phrases from given words. Not very efficient (because of Skip) but simple implementation:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> CreatePhrases(string[] words, int wordsCount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= words.Length - wordsCount; i++)
        yield return String.Join(" ", words.Skip(i).Take(wordsCount));
}
```

Rest is simple - split your string into words, build phrases, and get occurrences of each phrase in original string:

```
var my_string = "In the end this is not the end";
var words = my_string.Split();
var result = from p in CreatePhrases(words, 2)
             group p by p into g
             select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count()};
```

Result:

```
[
   Key: "In the", Count: 1,
   Key: "the end", Count: 2,
   Key: "end this", Count: 1,
   Key: "this is", Count: 1,
   Key: "is not", Count: 1,
   Key: "not the", Count: 1
]
```

---

More efficient way to create consecutive groups of items (works with any IEnumerable):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToConsecutiveGroups<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    // You can check arguments here            
    Queue<T> bucket = new Queue<T>();

    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        bucket.Enqueue(item);
        if (bucket.Count == size)
        {
            yield return bucket.ToArray();
            bucket.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

And all calculations could be done in one line:

```
var my_string = "In the end this is not the end";
var result = my_string.Split()
               .ToConsecutiveGroups(2)
               .Select(words => String.Join(" ", words))
               .GroupBy(p => p)
               .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
```

Comment: Yeeaahh, Regex in last line the best solution here

Comment: @gabba yep, best from me at 1 AM :) Instead of just return counts, I do distinct :)

Comment: Also your soultion would be beter if you write SplitToConsecutiveGroups method that iterate through source string and return enumerable of word groups

Comment: @gabba sorry, didn't get you. How your suggestion differs from my solution? Just extension to string instead of any enumerable?

Comment: When you do my_string.Split() you make full copy of words from source string. We dont need to store full copy here, just groupCount of words.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to deal with LARGE string, I would't recomend you to spliting whole string. 
You need to go through it, remember last groupCount words and count combinations in dictinary:

```
    var my_string = "In the end this is not the end";

    var groupCount = 2;

    var groups = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var lastGroupCountWordIndexes = new Queue<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < my_string.Length; i++)
    {
        if (my_string[i] == ' ' || i == 0)
        {
            lastGroupCountWordIndexes.Enqueue(i);
        }

        if (lastGroupCountWordIndexes.Count >= groupCount)
        {
            var firstWordInGroupIndex = lastGroupCountWordIndexes.Dequeue();

            var gruopKey = my_string.Substring(firstWordInGroupIndex, i - firstWordInGroupIndex);

            if (!groups.ContainsKey(gruopKey))
            {
                groups.Add(gruopKey, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                groups[gruopKey]++;
            }
        }

    }
```